# Proper usage of KID header for JWT tokens

Tags: jwt, cryptography, token, digital-signature, rfc

### Main Question

From what I understand based on RFC7515 it is just to hint which key was used for signing the JWS and that it is optional. I would like to gain some clarity on the practical aspects of it.

1. What are the proper use cases and scenarios where using KID is beneficial to make JWT tokens more secure, especially in the microservices architecture?
2. What are the cases where one key is used over the other
3. Is my method of assigning the KID of any use?

### Some Background Information

In my .env file, I have two dictionaries in the following manner

```
private_key = {'RANDOM_KID_GIBBER': 'PRIVATE_KEY.....'}
public_key = {'RANDOM_KID_GIBBER': 'CORRESPONDING_PUBLIC_KEY.....'}
```

I have set up my JWT token generator in this manner. I am certain that this is not the intended way of using the KID header and currently offers no form of security.

The default algorithm used is ES256 and I currently use them to generate access and refresh tokens.

```py
    def generate_token(
        self,
        username,
        jti,
        expire_duration,
        token_type,
        scopes=None,
        issuer=None,
        audience=None,
        ip_address=None,
        kid=None,
        private_claims=None,
    ):
        """
        Generates a token with the given parameters.
        """
        # if the KID is not specified select a random one
        if kid is None:
            kid = random.choice(list(config.PRIVATE_KEY.keys()))
        private_key = config.PRIVATE_KEY[kid]

        token_payload = {
            "jti": jti,
            "sub": username,
            "aud": audience,
            "iss": issuer,
            "exp": datetime.utcnow() + expire_duration,
            "iat": datetime.utcnow(),
            "nbf": datetime.utcnow(),
            "token_type": token_type,
            "ip": ip_address,
        }

        if scopes is not None:
            token_payload["scope"] = scopes

        if private_claims is not None:
            token_payload.update(private_claims) 

        headers = {"kid": kid}

        token = jwt.encode(
            token_payload, private_key, algorithm=config.JWT_ALGORITHM, headers=headers
        )

        return token_payload, token
```

The decoder then selects the appropriate key to decode using the KID header.